# passing list item in javascript

Tags: javascript, list

Can anyone please tell me how can I pass a list item from one page to another in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a list item?

Comment: This question is too vague. What type of data is the "list item"? Are both pages loaded in the browser when you want to pass, or do you want to load one page, have the user click a link, and load the next page with the list item data?

Comment: I think the question more focusses on the "passing information from page A to B" than the datatype.

Comment: there are characters in list items. yup both pages are loaded in the same browser.

Comment: @Jay, consider editing and clarifying your question, maybe by posting an example scenario of what you're trying to achieve.  You might then get answers that aren't just guessing at what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON. Perhaps as a querystring.

http://www.json.org/js.html

and

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/216.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming same origin:

Through the server:

1. push the list item through ajax
2. use cookies

Through local host:

- Use WebLocalStorage facility of HTML5
- Use Gears database
- Build a link to the page and use a "query" in the URI

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data required by the second page is available on the server.  If not, the first page should send it to the server via AJAX.

In either case, use JSTL on the server to create a data structure in JavaScript which is read by the second page after it loads

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax with JSON by POST ;)